# PHP 5 without Suhosin

Tags: php, suhosin, php-5.4

I'm planning an upgrade from Debian 6 (Squeeze) to 7 (Wheezy), which brings along php 5.4 and omits Suhosin.

Rightly or wrongly, Suhosin gives me a sense of security, because it lets me know about (some) hack attempts. e.g. I notice that my site gets a lot of hackers trying to send really long _GET variables, which are thwarted by Suhosin. I don't know how these long variables are used to hack stuff - perhaps a vulnerability that no longer exists in PHP 5.4?

I keep reading generalities like "oh, don't worry, loads of good bits from Suhosin have been adopted in PHP core now".

Can anyone summarise or point to **exactly which** of [Suhosin's features](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/a_feature_list.html) are included or unnecessary in PHP 5.4?

Comment: Squeeze? Wheezy? Are those Linux distributions? Can't you manually install Suhosin after updating your distro?

Comment: have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405053/is-php-5-4-safe-without-suhosin

Comment: @piddl0r yep, and  [I commented previously on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405053/is-php-5-4-safe-without-suhosin#comment24425407_14412121) -- it's exactly what I was talking about when I said generalities.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I've updated the question. Sorry, they're Debian codenames. Debian is a Linux-based OS very popular as a web server. Debian 7 (Wheezy) does not have the suhosin package, and I don't want to stray from package-based management.